# Dagre-D3 graph. Can egde path be customized?

Tags: d3.js, dagre-d3

I've managed to create some graph using dagre-d3 graph layout library. The library works wonderful but seems a bit lacking in documentation.

My graph really looks like this example: http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/interactive-demo.html

What I really want to do is to customize the edges so they will look like this picture:
[image]

So, basically, I need to customize the svg path element representing the edge. I did some research and it seems possible to use graphviz styles (arrows, colors, etc) but hasn't found any way to customize the connection path itself.

**Is it possible to customize it somehow**?

Comment: You could certainly select the respective path after it has been created and customise it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [this graph](https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/interactive-demo.html?graph=%2F*%20Example%20*%2F%0Adigraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20Note%3A%20HTML%20labels%20do%20not%20work%20in%20IE%2C%20which%20lacks%20support%20for%20%3CforeignObject%3E%20tags.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Brx%3D5%20ry%3D5%20labelStyle%3D%22font%3A%20300%2014px%20%27Helvetica%20Neue%27%2C%20Helvetica%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20edge%20%5BlabelStyle%3D%22font%3A%20300%2014px%20%27Helvetica%20Neue%27%2C%20Helvetica%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%5BlabelType%3D%22html%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22A%20%3Cspan%20style%3D%27font-size%3A32px%27%3EBig%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%3Cspan%20style%3D%27color%3Ared%3B%27%3EHTML%3C%2Fspan%3E%20Source!%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C%3B%0A%20%20%20%20E%20%5Blabel%3D%22Bold%20Red%20Sink%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%20%23f77%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20A%20-%3E%20B%20%5Bstyle%3D%22stroke%3A%20blue%3B%20stroke-width%3A%202px%3B%22%20lineInterpolate%3Dbasis%20arrowheadStyle%3D%22fill%3A%20blue%22%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20B%20-%3E%20C%3B%0A%20%20%20%20B%20-%3E%20D%20%5Blabel%3D%22A%20blue%20label%22%20labelStyle%3D%22fill%3A%20%2355f%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20D%20-%3E%20E%20%5Blabel%3D%22A%20thick%20red%20edge%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%20%23f77%3B%20stroke-width%3A%202px%3B%22%20arrowheadStyle%3D%22fill%3A%20%23f77%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C%20-%3E%20E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20A%20-%3E%20D%20%5BlabelType%3D%22html%22%20label%3D%22A%20multi-rank%20%3Cspan%20style%3D%27color%3Ablue%3B%27%3EHTML%3C%2Fspan%3E%20edge!%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%20blue%3B%20stroke-width%3A%202px%3B%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lineInterpolate%3Dbasis%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arrowhead%3Dnone%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20). It shows how to use styles on edges, change the way the edge is layed out (lineInterpolate), and how to remove the arrowhead.

For more details on styling, see https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3/wiki#demos. In particular, the following may be helpful:

- Style attributes: https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/style-attrs.html
- Built in shapes: https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/shapes
- Built in arrows: https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/arrows.html
- User defined shapes and arrows: https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/user-defined.html

Comment: Is it possible to draw an exact straight line from one node to another using D3 and Dagre-D3? Haven't had any problems with linear and basis but I'm trying to draw an exact straight line from one node to another.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** Adding the property `lineInterpolate: 'basis'` while setting your edges will draw curved edges. For example,

```
...
g.setEdge('A', 'B', { lineInterpolate: 'basis' });
...
```

See [this](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3/pull/123) PR for more details.

Comment: `lineInterpolate: 'basis'` appears to be out-of-date for curved edges.  Use `curve: d3.curveBasis` instead.  See the [Dagre D3 Demo: Style Attributes](https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/style-attrs.html) for an example of this and other styles.